# all USB "randomly" disconnect and reconnect

Tags: windows, usb, windows-8

I'm having a weird issue currently: at seemingly random times(although it seems to happen mostly when USB is used a lot, ie downloading + uploading over my WiFi stick or viewing an HD video from my external hard-drive) all my USB devices disconnect and reconnect after a few seconds. This wouldn't be a HUGE problem if I didn't have to rely on my USB for my internet, because now every time this happens my internet, and with it stuff like remote desktop, crashes.

I'm running Windows 8 Pro 64 bit with a Gigabyte 990FXA-D3 motherboard.

Now the weird thing: I had the same problem with my previous pc, which had a different motherboard(I think it was an Asus M4A785TD-V EVO).

I googled a bit and didn't really find anything about this, only found out I could check if something shows up in the Event Viewer, and I get this error there when the USB crashes: *"A timeout occurred while waiting for the EHCI host controller Interrupt on Async Advance Doorbell response."*

If you require any extra information I'm happy to provide it.

Comment: A quick search revealed [this useful article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2416007), which solved my problem.

Answer (score 9):

Best thing to do is (tech support tradition) unplug all of the usb devices, (including mouse+keyboard), choose a device, plug it in, restart, and wait...  It is possible that one of your devices is messing with the others, which would explain the same problem with a different motherboard.  I would try the flimsy looking devices first as they are more likely to fail.

Comment: I'm currently trying that and haven't been able to pin it down to anything yet(sometimes it just won't crash whatever I do for a couple of hours). The most likely candidate is my least flimsy looking device though: my USB microphone.

Comment: Did it crash with everything unplugged except the wifi chip?  Because that could be broken.

Answer (score 9):

I believe that the problem is with Windows 8 USB drivers and not from your hardware.

Recently a bought a WD Elements 1TB external HDD to backup all my stuff and I'm experiencing a similar problem: I was able to backup everything without any problem from my Windows 7 system. Then I installed Windows 8 (Pro x64) and when I'm trying to backup my data, the HDD just keeps disconnecting and reconnecting randomly.

I already tried to copy everything to another computer and I could do it without any problem. But when I connect the external HDD to the computer, it just keeps disconnecting and the reconnecting again, even when I'm not using it. And the HDD is the only thing that I have connected to USB ports, so it can't be any other USB device messing with it.

Have you tried to change the power settings and change the "USB selective suspend setting" to disabled? I heard some people saying that this solved their problem (but not for me).

Comment: USB selective suspend setting didn't fix it for me. I just ordered a pci-e wifi card now, because on the entire internet I can only find 2 topics about this specific problem: this one and one on the microsoft help site, both have no real solution.

Comment: I've had this same problem for about a week now and it definitely seems to be directly related to some kind of overload on the USB system as many others have posted. I couldn't find any real solution either, but I can say that turning off my external hard drives seems to cause the problem to stop. I'm not sure if it's a power draw issue though as both of those drives are externally powered with their own DC adapter. So if you're looking for a "fix" for the problem, try disconnecting other USB devices. I also found isolating the drives to USB 3.0 instead of 2.0 reduced the rate of disconnects.

Answer (score 9):

I had these disconnections and reconnections occur frantically while either copying files between 2 USB hard drives, and also when I ALWAYS had 2 or more USB devices that needs drivers installed in windows(ie no disconnections with USB fan devices). This occured with XP, VISTA, WINDOWS 7, and unfortunately with WINDOWS 8 as well. When I chose to trouble shoot only using 1 USB device HD plugged in, and copying files from USB HD to onboard motherboard HD, then I NEVER get disconnect RECONNECT issues. Only when I add ANOTHER USB device(altogether for this test 2 USB devices altogether) that appears to DRAW MORE power to operate the EXTRA devices, then when I intend to COPY files from 1 USB device to the onboard HD, OR copying between USB to USB HD's, then the disconnect RECONNET issues occur MORE frequently. When I use 1 usb HD connected and only a USB laptop fan connected, I NEVER get any disconnect reconnect problems. It appears ONLY with USB devices that draw MORE power than the USB FAN laptop base, THEN the EXTRA power being drawn from the motherboard to OPERATE the USB devices(with windows drivers), the motherboard tends to try to share the USB power among ALL the USB devices, and the voltage drop may cause one of the USB devices to stop working momentarily then reconnect after the motherboard tries to share power to the device again.

There is a limit to the voltage being used(SHARED) for ALL the USB ports, and when you use the device like USB HD's, for that momentary OPERATION request(copying reading writing files), there is an EXTRA draw of power to that USB device. IF there are MULTIPLE USB devices, then if ALL of them DRAW power to operate a function(keyboard/mouse and MOST OBVIOUSLY HARD DRIVES), then the device needing MORE power may fall BELOW its minimum power requirement and so cannot operate efficiently, and momentarily stops working, UNTIL the power level returns to its EFFICIENT level.

******BASICALLY,
If copying FILES, I just removed ALL the other devices, and plugged in 1 USB HD and copied FIRST to the motherboard HD, then to copy to the 2nd USB HD I removed the 1st USB HD, plugged in the 2nd USB HD, and copied/moved from the motherboard HD to the new 2nd USB HD.******

NO ISSUES there after.

This is the only work around, since the DISCONNECT RECONNECT is a power sharing issue with the USB ports. This is really a motherboard design issue, so nothing you can do about it. This problem occured with ALL the laptops I used.

This might not work with the USB SHARING HUBS that use external power supply to MAINTAIN the voltage shared by all devices. However this has OTHER issues related to USB 2 or 3.0 supported devices, and whether the LAPTOP has the same USB 2 or 3.0 ports(either only 1 of the ports are USB 3.0 or ALL of them are the same).

BE COOL

Hope this makes thing clear.

Answer (score 9):

Found a solution here

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1783536/usb-ports-disconnecting-reconnecting.html

and it worked for me:

1. Scroll to the right and type 'Power Options' in the search field and click on it.
2. Click 'Change plan setting' on your chosen plan.
3. Click 'Change advanced power setting' on your chosen plan.
4. Find 'USB settings' and open.
5. Find 'USB selective suspend setting' and change it to disabled.

Comment: Some devices not following the USB standard may indeed trip over USB power options. I had a cheap USB key that indeed encountered this problem...

Comment: This setting was already disabled for me, yet I'm still getting the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be indeed a connection here, iv been trying for a while to search on google for this spesific problem.. kinda hard to figure out a search term, disconnect reconnect, stopped working, but all those shows up other types of problem.. anyway

My connection here is, i have TONS of usb devices, and sometimes 2 of my usb harddrives + my mouse (only those 3) suddenly stops working, then reconnects a few seconds later (annoying if it happends while im playing).

And lately iv been messing around whit it to try to figure out the cause.

Apparently if i remove the two usb hd's the problem hasnt happend again for a week now and still running whiout the disconnect problem.

I tought before it was like a hardware issue.. but iv switched mb since then.
Then i tought it was power saveing in windows 8 that was disconnecting a few usb devices (while said devices are in use), so i went berzerk in power options, setting it to maximum performance, and everything inside advanced options to never on, never sleep ect.. + into hardware devices under usb controller where its also checked by default turn off device to save power... so i removed that too...

and still after all that, mouse + hds still do the disconnect reconnect dance..

The only thing that works is disconnecting the two usb hds..

Iv also tried lately to put all my usb devices on a usb hub whit its own powersupply incase my 1200w PSU for whatever reson would not be able to supply power to 10 devices, rangeing from webcam, mouse, keyboard, 2 usb hds, usb drawingpad A4, keypad and so on, usb wireless network device too.. 
But that makes no difference.

Iv also tried while playing games to stream like video and music + copying large files from the usb drives randomly, in case its a stress problem, but nope.. it just seems completely random disconnect reconnects.

somedays it never disconnects reconnects at all.. and some days like onec every hour or so..

Im not sure why the mouse doesnt do that when the harddrives arnt connected, it wont disconnect reconnect.. and 3 devices does it in perfect sync everytime, but none of the other usb devices does it.

My usb mouse is a razor, iv read on net that they might have been made whit low quality, maybe theres a electric problem that those 3 products are low quality and maybe have too much resistance or maybe just simply leaks from one circut to another and the computer just simply restarts them when the charge gets too low or high or whatever... but i guess that doesnt make sence since those are the only 3 usb devices that does the disconnect reconnect, and the fact theyr on a usb hub now.

Maybe its a addressing problem? irq or whatever its called? im not sure how that works since usb is claimed to handle over 250 devices if not more, and since only 2 of the devices are hd and the other one is mouse, yet nothing else usb related disconnects reconnects... ever

Its not a problem whit updates or drivers considering same thing happend in windows 7 before i upgraded to windows 8, windows updater updates as it pleases too.

If anyone has any idea what else i can try or suggest something i might have missed, ill try that.

As far as i can see, my only option is to remove the hds and get a network storage devices to take over the job as external hds, since for me the disconnect reconnect only happends when those 3 devices are connected (i allways have them connected, cus i allways use them), and this fixes my problem now.

Sorry about my english, im norwegian (its a curse).

And hopefully other people will be able to figure more stuff out, since at this point iv given up...

---

08.03.2013 - Updated current post.

---

I formated my pc again, and yep, as suspected "disconnect recconect" problem still is there.

And as i explained poorly above, the only fix seems to be unplugging the ONE of the TWO external-HD.

So if anyone reads this post, check how many usb devices you have and try to reduce number to just keyboard and mouse, and see if that helps you.

*Iv read up on net again, and there seem's to be alot of 64-bit os related to this problem.*

*IRQ adresses can maybe have something to do whit this, but i have no idea how it works, and why the hds and mouse would run fine then suddenly "disonnect reconnect" then continue to run fine*

- maybe this is the connection whit IRQ adresses :

like external hd isnt in use that sends a shutdown note to IRQ address thats shared whit hd's and mouse's leading to a shutdown.

Then as mouse would report movement and send another note that IRQ adress is in use and enable it again right after*

Comment: Well, I figured SOMETHING out. I tried a lot of stuff though. I solved it by doing either one of these things:

- My WiFi USB stick replaced with a pci-e card
- Disconnected my Steelseries Sensei mouse, replaced it with another

Answer (score 1):

Maybe having so many USB devices is tripping an internal "circuit breaker". Kind of like what happens if you plug in an AC, refrigerator, coffee maker, and microwave into the same wall socket in your house and turn them on all at once. Do your USB devices have external power sources or are they all drawing power solely from the USB port(s)?

Comment: I suspect this may be a factor. I'm going to try plugging some of my higher-power devices into a powered USB hub so it's not trying to draw it all from the motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

Was just on this site looking for help with my internet adapter that was causing the same issue and i tried going to device manager, (network adapter), power management and un-checking the box that said "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" and so far my adapter has stayed connected along with my other usb devices while downloading, i hope this helped some of you guys.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this issue for quite a while. So, I thought about sharing what I have found.

### Severity assessment

Open Event Viewer -> Create a custom filter by source = usbehci.

It should mainly print errors like "A timeout occurred while waiting for the EHCI host controller Interrupt on Async Advance Doorbell response." or its less severe sibling "A retry was required for the EHCI Host Controller to acknowledge the doorbell request.".

If these errors occur too often / time interval Windows will shutdown the device and possibly show something like "USB device has malfunctioned".

### Base line

Windows 7 x64, USB devices: mouse and keyboard on USB, TL-WN722N wireless adapter and an external HDD. Sometimes another HDD is plugged in for backup. Everything is powered from the mainboard, no problems.

### Windows 10 issues

The exact same hardware. Remove USB suspend, updated USB driver from the manufacturer. A simple speed test from the Internet provider creates the issue within several seconds. **I managed to greatly improve the situation by:**

- changing wireless adapter with one that have proper drivers for Windows 10 (small one from Edimax)
- using an externally powered USB hub
- using a USB 2.0 port instead of a 3.0 one
- avoiding having many active connections at the same time

Note: USB powered HDDs do not have any issues, so the problem seems to be more driver related than power related.

I think a PCI wireless adapter should perform better, but I have not tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with my Windows To Go installation on my laptop. USB drives gets randomly disconnected. Solved it by closing the laptop lid(making it sleep) then opening it again. Somehow after it has resumed, the devices does not get disconnected anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen these issues on few computers.  The way I was able to fix them was to uninstall the USB & chipset drivers from the device manager & then go to the manufacturer's website for the motherboard and install the newest chipset and USB drivers.  That seemed to do the trick for me.