# USB ports randomly disconnecting? other issue? - Should I just replace mobo?

Tags: windows, usb, motherboard

For over a year I have been trying to solve the problem of my USB ports 'randomly' disconnecting. At least, I think that's what it is since I hear the usb connect/disconnect sound.

**The problem example:**
When I play a game and I run with 'd' and press it for a long time, it will 'stick'. (Note that the keyboard does not literally stick, the key just keeps getting registered) When pressing the same key again it 'unsticks'. The mouse has the same thing, it keeps moving to one side. However the mouse can't be 'unstuck'. I have not experienced problems with my webcam, mic or any other USB items I've tried.

I found this thread a while back and have tried every single solution in this thread: [all USB "randomly" disconnect and reconnect](https://superuser.com/questions/488186/all-usb-randomly-disconnect-and-reconnect) and nothing worked.

Stuff I'm using:

- Intel i5-4460
- ASUS H97-Pro
- Radeon r9 280

When the problem specifically occurs:

- When holding a key for a long period of time
- When pressing a lot of keys at the same time
- Randomly when using the mouse
- Problem seems to be worse when playing games (or maybe just more noticeable then?)
- This is not something that *always* happens, it can be fine for days.

What I've tried:

- Tried different kinds of keyboards and mouses.
- Updated everything there was to update. Windows, BIOS, drivers, everything.
- Tried windows 7, 8 and 10.
- Did a complete wipe of my pc and reinstalled everything
- Switching from USB2.0 to 3.0. 2.0 seems to be the most stable.
- Checked for short circuits, checked all wires, cables, overheating etc.
- Tried the 'tomshardware' solution (advanced usb power plan)
- Contacted ASUS support. They claim their product is not the issue.
- Checked for 'sticky keys' option in Windows

Obviously at this point I'm incredibly annoyed and I just want to be able to play games again. **I am thinking of just buying a new mobo, but how big is the chance that this is actually causing the problem?**

I have the feeling selling my current mobo will be hard and that means I've wasted a good 100 euro.

Comment: Are your devices connected to a rear-Mobo hub, or to the front of your case? If they are to the front of your case, have you tried re-seating any cables that run from the front panel to the Mobo?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Rear mobo hub, problem occurs with every single usb port, rear or front.

Comment: Just to be sure, is your power supply sufficient/functioning well?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf it should be, but someone just gave me the tip of trying an external usb hub with it's own power source, so I'm ordering one right now to see if that helps.